# JavaFX can't load recource

Tags: java, javafx

When I try start resource I get exeption:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.

Even though path is correct. (Tested with full path also).
Also tried rebuild project. I use Intellij and project is vuild using Maven.

```
public class ViewManager {
Scene scene;

public ViewManager(Scene scene){
    this.scene = scene;
}
public void showLoginScreen () {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../view/loginView.fxml"));
    try {
        scene.setRoot(loader.load());
        LoginController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.initManager(this);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

[image: Project structure]

Comment: You cannot use relative paths with `Class.getResource`. You have to use an absolute path: `getResource("/superpackage/view/loginView.fxml")` where `superpackage` is the parent package of the package containing your class with `.` replaced with `/`

Comment: Is `..` syntax actually supported by `getResource`?

Comment: that worked when I used in simple JavaFX build project will edit question with project struckture

Comment: for fabian, tried using absulute path that didn't worked either

Comment: @Sande what exactly have you tried? note that your example looks like "superpackage" == "", so "/view/loginView.fxml" should work provided the native filesystem correctly handles uppercase letters (edited, keyboard betrayed me ;)

Comment: @James_D darn keyboard ;) ... thanks for the correction

Comment: @kleopatra yes that exacly what I used and also did't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when using maven project, you need mark as recourse folder or move to maven build recourse folder